# Passing a 2D array as an argument

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor

I'm having some problems regarding syntax around using constructors that take 2D arrays as parameters. Here's an example of one such constructor:

```
template <class T>
Node<T>::Node(T d[4][4]) : data(d) {}
```

I'm attempting to use it as follows:

```
float f[4][4] = { { /* 2D array declaration */ } };
Node<float> myNode = Matrix4x4<float>((f));
```

I'm getting the following errors, and after much searching around, I can't figure out the root cause of the problem:

```
error: no matching constructor for
      initialization of 'Node<float>'
      Node<float> myNode = Node<float>((f));
                   ^     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/Node.h:33:5: note: candidate constructor not viable:
      no known conversion from 'Node<float>' to
      'float (*)[4]' for 1st argument
      Node(T d[4][4]);
```

Obviously the line "`no known conversion from 'Node<float>' to 'float (*)[4]' for 1st argument`" is a big clue, but I'm stuck on why clang++ is interpreting `f` as a `float (*)[4]` instead of as `float[4][4]`.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Because raw arrays can't be passed by value to functions. An array parameter is always treated as a pointer to the element type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntax is

```
void f(T (&d)[4][4])
```

but prefer `std::array<std::array<T, 4>, 4>` which is copyable